# error: ‘boost::Q_FOREACH’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-multi-index

I'm using boost 1.54 and Qt version 5.2.1.

I'm getting the following error when I try to build the package

```
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp:927:10: error: 'boost::Q_FOREACH’ has not been declared
 boost::foreach::tag
        ^

/usr/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:1399:10: error: ‘boost::Q_FOREACH’ has not been declared
 boost::foreach::tag)
    ^
```

Checked the header in `sequenced_index.hpp`, `ordered_index.hpp`, they both have `foreach_fwd.hpp` and `foreach.hpp` included.
I tried including `CONFIG += no_keywords` in the project file `(.pro)`. But still I'm getting this error. I'm not sure what's the reason.

Comment: Do you have a macro named `foreach` defined that expands to `Q_FOREACH`?

Comment: Did you re-run qmake after adding no_keywords to the CONFIG?

Comment: @MrEricSir: Thanks. I don't get that error anymore but I got a new error `error: expected ‘:’ before ‘slots’;`
`error: ‘slots’ does not name a type`
`error: ‘signals’ does not name a type`
 
I tried following this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots). And the above error is gone. Now I am getting weird errors.

Comment: If you have a new question, the thing to do is to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this problem has been [circumvented](https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/commit/bbad86c193ef703e990dd23b0a9edb327e11de34) for the upcoming Boost 1.60 release so that you can let Qt define the macro `foreach`.